# Как проще всего сымитировать репозиторий (данные)

Tags: c#, repository, mocking

У меня есть интерфейс репозитория, например:

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    IEnumerable<User> ListUsers();
    User GetUserById(int id);
    void AddUser(User user);
    void DeleteUser(User user);
    void EditUser(User user);
}
```

где *User*, например, выглядит так:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Role> { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

на всякий случай,

```
public class Role 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Как **проще всего** сделать имитацию данного репозитория с фейковыми данными?

- Если просто сделать *singleton* внутри которого определить `List<User>`, то это меня смущает, потому что будут отличия в поведении от реального репозитория. Если в реальном репозиторие два раза сделать `GetUser(id)` (с одним и тем же `id`), то получим два экземпляра объекта. А если в *singleton*-е или статическом классе так же будем 2 раза доставать из `List<>`, то получаем один экземпляр объекта.
- Если делать *Text File* или *XML*, то вроде как долго. Хотелось бы максимально простой вариант найти. Но если это самый простой вариант, то скажите, тогда сам отвечу, что получилось. Что касается *SQLite*, то тем более городить долго, не стоит того.
- Если использовать *Моки*, то смущает, что у меня почти нет с ними опыта работы, и то, что данные (например, имя, Email) будут выглядеть не красиво. Кажется, в моей ситуации проще самому ввести как-то данные для 5-10 пользоватей.

**UPDATE:** Сохранять состояние достаточно в рамках одного сеанса работы программы. После ее выключения, можно сбрасывать добавленных или измененных `User`-ов

Comment: Вам для тестов или для другого?

Comment: @andreycha, нет, не для тестов. Делаю юзер-интерфейс. Пока не готова серверная часть (день-три дня), сделал заглушки для клиентских сервисов. Потом, с помощью _IoC_ подменю их реализациями, которые будут обращаться к реальным серверным сервисам.

Comment: Когда имитировал отчеты, то понравилось использовать [**NBuilder + Faker**](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/creating-test-data-with-nbuilder-and-faker) для генерации _рандомных_ данных. Ими можно так же удобно пользоваться для первоначального наполнения листа, если пользоваться ответом Qwertiy "Статический класс".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Статический класс, но отдавать и сохранять в нём всегда копии объектов, а не сами объекты. Естественно, имеются в виду глубокие копии.

Comment: Здорово! Попробую по [этому](http://stackoverflow.com/a/78612/2772330) варианту делать копии. Производительность меня не так волнует для _Фейкового Репозитория_.  Галку, может быть попозже поставлю.

Answer (score 3):

Советую рассмотреть [фреймворк Moq](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/18.5.php)

Не рекомендую юзать фейковый класс-репозиторий, т.к.

1. Интерфейсов в приложении множество, фейков будет также не мало, и
   при изменении интерфейса (добавлении нового метода, к примеру) нужно
   будет помнить о необходимости имплементации изменений фейками

   В общем это грозит тем, что поддерживать никто не захочет фейки
2. Определённо захочется (а в большинстве случаев просто необходимо) написать хотя бы с десяток тестов на тот или иной метод, как следствие - появляется проблема в пересечении данных. Данные подходящие для одного теста, не подходят для другого

Moq (или аналог) позволяет в рамках каждого теста создавать свой уникальный набор данных для работы

Comment: Спасибо! Я думаю, чем разбираться с новым для меня фреймворком, проще сейчас сделать фейки (именно в данной моей ситуации). Еще, т.к. делаю клиента, то тестов нет. Заглушки - временная мера. Зато есть _IoC_. С ходу не представляется, как регистрировать такой _мок_, чтобы ничего кроме одной строчки регистрации в будущем менять было не надо. Но ответ в тему и полезный.

Comment: Кстати, а как в _moq_ делать _рандомные_ данные? Они хотя бы симпатично выглядят или чего-то типа `Name01, Name02, Name03...`? Еще, если методы сервиса асинхронные, то можно пользоваться этим фреймворком?